# How to successfully set a value to a field in JS? tried on.focus but no luck

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, field, frontend

Hi I'm trying to get my input field to say 'Enter your e-mail address' and when you click on it, it goes away to let the user type it. I tried playing around with on:focus and other various tips on SO but I couldn't manage to get it working. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction? You can see what I'm talking about at heyscout.com.

In my script tags, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
JotForm.init(function(){
   $('input_1').hint('Enter your e-mail address');
});
</script>
```

For my input field, I have

```
        <div id="cid_1" class="form-input">
          <input type="email" class="form-textbox validate[required, Email]" id="input_1" name="q1_stayIn1" size="30"  />
        </div> 
            <button class="signup_btn" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
              Okay!
            </button>
```

It should be working but I'm not completely sure what's the issue.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't already know, you can do this with plain HTML if you don't need to support older browsers.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address" class="form-textbox validate[required, Email]" id="input_1" name="q1_stayIn1" size="30" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it:

```
$('#input_1').hint('Enter your e-mail address');
   ^--------------- YOU NEED THIS TO SELECT ID
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector is used just like CSS, so you need to target it like `#input_1`, e.g.,

```
$('#input_1').hint('Enter your e-mail address');
```